# Android notification app icons not showing in Nexus

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to get the app icons like below red color one in in my notification bar. but still showing like the 1st AppName notification

[image]

I used the code like this in the firebaseMessageingService class

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(LocalRepository.getNotificationId(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

I have changed the  targetSdkVersion 20 in my gradle as well. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support Lollipop Material Icons then make transparent icons for Lollipop.

Notification Builder can be implemented by following method for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
  } else { 
         mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
  }
```

Comment: May I know the different images between the icon_transperent and icons?
How do I generate this?

Comment: you can ask your designer.you have to make just border of icon rest of the thing is transparent.

Comment: I have changed the code and I generate the transparent icons and still It's showing the same thing

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_trans);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }

Comment: @CarinaMj : By android 5.0 , you need to set transparent small icon in notification to show it and its best size is 64x64 px

Comment: @JinalPatel still I got the same... I have changed everything 
Please check my screen shot of the notification in below answer

Comment: Yeah it's working in the other mobiles 
not working after android 5.0

Comment: so it is problem with icon.

Comment: Hi, is this necessary to change the targetSDKVersion to 20 ?? 
also I have created the new custom layout then it's working but in the status bar icon still showing as white space can you explain me ??

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Check this exactly I need like the red color notification 
but mine still showing the same.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }


compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 9
    versionName "2.0.1"
```

Comment: Edit your question, instead of added extra information as an answer. (and don't use `setSmallIcon()` when you want to set a large icon, use `setLargeIcon`)